# Profile Picture under top navigation controller ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

[image]im haveing trouble with displaying the profile image and the name of the user once they have logged in, in the storyboard the FBProfilePictureView is placed below the topNavBar and aswell as the name of the user but once the app begins to run on the simulator the name and the profile image are place under neath the topNavBar im wondering why and how to fix this issue

Comment: any screen shots and code ?? would be much easy to understand

Comment: use customized bar button  or create bar button item progrmatically

Comment: ok i will put some code in just give me a sec

Comment: for some reason it just fixed itself i have no idea how though